# Repeat row names in R

Tags: r

I have a column with 4 (actually 40) names in it:
Fred
Chris
Matt
Joe

I need a .csv that repeats each of the 4 names 4 times like so:
Fred
Fred
Fred
Fred
Chris
Chris
...

Any help would is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: `rep(c("Fred","Chris","Matt","Joe"), each=4)`? Is that all you are trying to do? Maybe with `write.csv(rep(c("Fred","Chris","Matt","Joe"), each=4),"ok.csv", row.names=F)`?

Comment: And what if I have my 40 names in a data frame? Using that method it creates 4 columns of names instead of 1 column with the names repeating. Thank you

Comment: You are saying that you ran the above code and got 4 columns of data? That doesn't seem right and doesn't agree with what I get when I run the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what did it:

df[rep(seq(nrows(df)),each=4),]